# Two identical bits of kit with different voltage... trying to cannibalise parts

Tags: power-supply

My 250V UV ballast box blew its control board.  I bought a identical model on ebay from the US and when it arrived the plate on the back stated 90-130VAC.  I was hopping the US item was dual voltage so I could just start using it.  If it was not, my plan was to swap in the power supply from my dud 250V box.

Opened the US box and saw that the internal components were identical to my 250V box.  I have attached a photo of the components with a close up of the power supply and circuit breaker from the US box.  The labels are IDENTICAL on the US and UK boxes.  I therefore thought that there should be no problem running the new US box off the UK 250V supply.  When I turned it on it worked but after a minute there was a smell of burning.  I discovered this was coming from the fan, which on close inspection has a 115V label on it.

My question is about the power supply unit.  Can someone please interpret the circuit diagram on the label for me.  Is it possible that this unit puts out 115 or 250V depending on the input?  I find this hard to believe.  However, it would explain why the US box has a 115V fan that is burning up with the 250 V input.  One last piece of info is that all the brown wires that I can get the meter on are showing 250VAC when I connect the UK mains.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Here is a photo of the board.  It does not look like would be easy to convert it to run on 250V.  I therefore think it would be best to add a chassis transformer after the emi.  What do you guys think?

[image]

Comment: The silver thing is not a power supply.  It is a line filter to remove noise from the power line- or more correctly to prevent noise from the device from getting back out to the power line.  It even says "EMI filter" on it.  That is an "electromagentic interference filter."  The power supply will probably be on what you called the control board.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  So, can you confirm that I am right in thinking that if I put 120V into the EMI filter, 120 will come out?  I think that is what you are saying.

Comment: What ever voltage you put into it will come out of it.  It doesn't change the voltage, it just removes noise.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a power supply, it's a line filter: -

[image]

> Is it possible that this unit puts out 115 or 250V depending on the
>   input?

NO!

Comment: Actually the answer is literally yes: Depending on the input it will output exactly what's on the input minus HF EMI, so depending on the input it _will_ output 110V, 120V, 200V, 240V... I'm not sure if this is what the OP means, but I sort of think so.

Comment: @Asmyldof I think you're stretching it!!

Comment: No, I honestly think he meant to ask "Does this output different voltages, depending on what voltage is on the input", but I am not sure, else I would edit the question. i.e. "If I put 240V on, will 240 come out, and if I put 115 on, will 115 come out?", Which: Yes.

Comment: @Asmyldof the op believes it is a power supply (incorrectly) and I assume that he thinks it will (somehow) produce a regulated output of 115 volts if the input voltage is (say) between 85V and 150V. If above 150V then the output = 250V. That's how I read it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  I did think the EMI was a power supply (or voltage regulator/transformer) from the look and position of the thing.  However, it should be clear from the post that I did suspect that the unit would output whatever voltage went in.  I think this is now established from the consensus of answers.  The question now is whether I blew the new control board from the US box then I powered it up.  And if not, what is the best way to convert this bit of kit to work on 250v.  I will post a photo of the board in a while when I get back to the lab.  Thanks one and all

Comment: Please see new photo and an additional question above it.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Please see new photo and an additional question above it. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I have no idea what rating that device is in the new photograph at all - do you have a circuit diagram? If not then get tracing one out - can't be that hard but this is going beyond your original question now.

Comment: It is not just going beyond my original question, it is beyond my expertise.  Thanks for all your answers.  Next time I buy kit from the US I will have a 120V autotransformer to power it up.  Just out of interest, can you tell me what the components marked BR1 and TH4 are called?

Comment: BR1 is probably a bridge rectifier and TH4 is difficult to identify but I suspect they are over-voltage devices (that may now be Blown) or they may be inrush current limiters - without the circuit it's impossible to say and yes, this is definitely going beyond your original question.